# catkin_make package that uses mavros_msgs

Tags: ros, mavlink, catkin, mavros, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working on a package to test the idea of controlling my robot over /mavros/rc_override topic. I made a package via `catkin_create_pkg` and added `mavros` and `mavros_msgs` to the `find_packages` part in the CMakeLists.txt and also added both to the `package.xml`. Then writing the code and using `#include "mavros_msgs/RCIn.h"`as suggested (or with `<` and `>`.

After saving and doing the `catkin_make` in the catkin workspace root directory, it fails as it says it can not find `mavros_msgs`. When I delete that from the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`, it falls as it tells me it does not `#include "mavros_msgs/RCIn.h"` (same if I use `<` and `>`).

As I haven't done much with cmake and catkin I came here to find a solution. I have been searching the internet but couldn't find an example that fits my requirements.

Thanks for your time

Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219489/catkin_make-package-that-uses-mavros_msgs/) by [mbeentjes](https://answers.ros.org/users/24675/mbeentjes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-10-20**:
What you are doing sounds generally reasonable, so the error must lie in the details. Please post the relevant parts of `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` along with the exact compiler error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you install the mavros_msgs package? The fact that catkin doesn't find it is suspicious.

You could try and find the package via command line: `$ catkin_find mavros_msgs`. If you can't find it you will need to get the package first.

---

Originally posted by [nyquist09](https://answers.ros.org/users/24686/nyquist09/) with karma: 191 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-10-20**:
Mavros depends on msgs, so it should be installed.

**Comment by [mbeentjes](https://answers.ros.org/users/24675/mbeentjes/) on 2015-10-21**:
Executing `catkin_find mavros_msgs` gives me no results.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the relevant catkin howto document: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/cpp_msg_dependencies.html .

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What version of mavros installed? Because mavros_**msgs** introduced in version 0.14 (current stable 0.15).

So perhaps you use old release, where all messages in packages itself mavros/mavros_extras.
I recommend to build from source, but for that you must update mavlink package (from shadow repo: [ros-jade-mavlink](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-jade-mavlink/))

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mbeentjes](https://answers.ros.org/users/24675/mbeentjes/) on 2015-10-21**:
Doing `catkin_find mavros` returns me a directory `/opt/ros/indigo/include/mavros` and that contains the messages I need. So now I have to determine how to get that working within catkin. It seems I do not have change my `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-10-21**:
Cat `/opt/ros/indigo/shared/mavros/package.xml`.
RTFM: https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md#source-installation

**Comment by [mbeentjes](https://answers.ros.org/users/24675/mbeentjes/) on 2015-10-21**:
Using mavros 0.13.0. At the moment executing `source /opt/ros/indigo/devel/setup-mavros.bash` gives me an error: `/opt/ros/indigo/lib/mavros/mavros_node: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/indigo/lib//libmavros_plugins.so: undefined symbol: mavlink_get_channel_status`. So that's something I'm solving now

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-10-21**:
Update your installation to 0.15. Deb packages can be found in shadow-fixed repo.

- [libmavconn](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-libmavconn/)
- [mavros_msgs](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-mavros-msgs/)

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-10-21**:\

- [mavros](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-mavros/)
- [mavros_extras](http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-mavros-extras/)

**Comment by [mbeentjes](https://answers.ros.org/users/24675/mbeentjes/) on 2015-10-22**:
Doing a little research if this can be done without problems (using ErleRover with ErleBrain v1) so I don't got to fix other issues. Is it a big issue on not updating?

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-10-22**:
Several bug in setpoint plugins (quaternion->yaw, some transforms).